# multiple layouts for multi-site architecture in angular js

Tags: css, angularjs, templates

We have a multi-site architecture in our angular app where base-URL of domain changes for each site. For each site we need a header and footer to be included and the css and links in the header and footer change for each site.

how to include the header html and css relevant for a site dynamically in angular js?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem twice with different approaches.

1st time: I dynamically added header and footer components based on the site being loaded and loaded custom theme for each site

2nd time: We moved our angular app inside our laravel application and used dynamic header and footer from laravel. so completely removed this requirement from angular app. This works great.

Answer (score -1):

When i understand your problem correctly you should export your Header, Footer [..] as an "private" external Angular Module. So you can reuse it in every new project.

for example

Project 1

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
import { YourHeaderModule } from './your-header.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    ...
    YourHeaderModule
    ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

Than you can use it just like an Material Module/Component.

Comment: there are no multiple projects. In the same project there is possibility of multiple site

Comment: OP's question is about *different* header and footer per site, not a single shared header and footer as this answer proposes.